# Android - Token not showed when implementing GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following google's [gide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) on implementing GCM ([using this files](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)) and I cannot see the token in the logkat:

```
Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
```

in the RegistrationIntentService.java file

Comment: what can i say .... **it is working for me** ... device do not support GCM? you f* up packages names?

Answer (score 0):

Please review #2 and #3 [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start). It could be that your project cannot find the project number which is specified in the google-services.json file.

Comment: I did. Surprisingly there are two client_id in the json file: `android:gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart` and mine `android:net.udazz.udazz`. The same happens with the package_name